How to download old versions of AG-Grid
I'm struggling to find where I can download old versions of AG Grid from. We're using 23.0. I want to upgrade to 30.2 (from 31 the API has several breaking changes, but I cannot find where to download the old versions from. I'm not familiar with GitHub so maybe they're hidden there.
Can anyone help?
I'm using Windows so I want the tar ball - I can't use apt.

In their Git Hub releases there are tar.gz asset: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/releases/tag/v30.2.1

@Justinas Those are the sources from the GitHub repository itself at that tag. If you look at the latest releases, it includes a lot of other files as well.

Ideally I'd like the min files, e.g. ag-grid-community.min.js

@MarkRotteveel OP for some reason asked for tar files, nothing mentioned about NPM

You can get a list of the different versions here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-community?activeTab=versions
Installing a specific version, in your case 30.2.1 can be accomplished like this:
npm i ag-grid-community@30.2.1

If you need the tar file, you can access it here:
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/archive/refs/tags/v30.2.1.tar.gz
